# SQL Developer won't start - only from terminal

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, java-home

I downloaded SQL Developer 4.1.3.20.
Before that, I installed JDK 8.
I am using a MacBook with El Capitan.

Now, when I start it by clicking on the symbol, it shows a bar with about 10% loaded but never continues to load.
Thanks to stackoverflow I found out that I can start the SQL developer from the terminal by calling /Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh, which works normally.

I found a product.conf under /.sqldeveloper/4.1.0 and changed the path to the JAVA_HOME. Because that did not make sense to me, I also created a folder names 4.1.3 and 4.1.3.20, copied the same file there.  Did not make a difference.

I also checked the script itself, and it uses the current path to my Java home with the option "-v 1.8".

I can't see why it works in the terminal but not when I click the symbol.

EDIT

Now it also won't work any more in the terminal. I get the exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1329)
    at oracle.ideimpl.MainWindowImpl.<init>(MainWindowImpl.java:166)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.Activator.setupWindow(Activator.java:281)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalStart(EquinoxLauncher.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.start(EquinoxLauncher.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.start(Netigso.java:191)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.startFramework(NetigsoHandle.java:209)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1352)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1156)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed an older version (4.1.0) and, surprisingly, it worked.